# Windows UI Automation not showing all child elements?

Tags: c#, windows, ui-automation

I have a TreeView control on my form, and I'm recursively going through the elements of another window starting with the window itself. I'm  using this to find the elements:

```
getRecursiveElements(AutomationElement parent)
{
  children = parent.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);

  foreach (AutomationElement child in children)
  {
    addToTreeView(child);
    getRecursiveElements(child);
  }
}
```

Generally speaking, the code works quite well in most cases. The tree is populated and I have a bit of other supporting code allowing me to double click, for example, an element in the tree-view and it will highlight that element on the target form.

The issue I'm having is that, while it generates an awesome tree, there are still some elements missing for certain target programs.

What possible reason could there be for this, and is there any way to get around it?
If I call `EnumChildWindows()` from user32.dll will that have the same problem?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the types of elements it's skipping over? And have you compared your tree against the one produced by the UISpy or Inspect tools from the SDK? UIA does have a concept of 'views', which is a filter that is applied in addition to the condition you supply to Find. By default, UIA filters out things that are not content elements, so if you enumerate a listbox or listview, you'll get just the listbox, but not the scrollbars or the  header. Is this the sort of thing you're missing, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all programs use separate windowed controls for all their logical children. Mostly this depends on the GUI framework used.

As an extreme example, Qt uses a single window for each top-level window. It then paints all the widgets on the form from the form's WM_PAINT message handler.

Programs that take this approach are typically impossible to automate through generic methods.

It sounds like you have encountered an application that uses some windowed controls but also uses custom controls with a single window for what appears to be multiple widgets. Again this is quite common.

Comment: To the OP: I'd still like an example of where this is failing: apps that don't use HWNDs are supposed to implement either MSAA or UIAutomation so that they will be accessible by users with disabilities - and also end up being testable/automatable. For example, WPF, Silverlight and Flash and the document areas of IE and Firefox don't use HWNDs for their child elements, but because they implement these interfaces, you can still enumerate them with UIA. I'm wondering what the 'certain target programs' are, since they likely also have accessibility issues; I'm curious if these are well-known apps.

Comment: (FWIW, QT apparently implements MSAA - so even though it only uses a single HWND, it should still be enumerable using UIA - since UIA uses MSAA as a source of information internally. Whether UI is enumerable with UIA is more complex than whether simply whether it uses HWNDs for child elements; it can also depend on whether the framework has accessibility support, and if it has, whether the developer of the app has correctly used it.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a better example of what fails? Thinking about the problem, it may be that the 'element' in the other form is being drawn manually, and so doesn't have distinct registered handles for everything.