# Controlling external Qt application - Open File

Tags: c#, qt, ui-automation

I need to be able to control an external Qt application so that I can open a file in the application.

I have tried using Process to get the Window Handle and then via PInvoke using GetMenu, GetSubMenu and GetMenuItemID to get all the parameters for using SendMessage and "Click" on the open menu in the external application

This works perfectly if I try it with Notepad as the external app, but not with the actual application which is written using Qt.

I do get the Window handle but GetMenu returns 0.

I have this code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetMenu(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSubMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetMenuItemID(IntPtr hMenu, int nPos);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenDocument("notepad", "test.doc");
}

public void OpenDocument(string windowTitle, string document)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = GetWindow(windowTitle);
    IntPtr hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
    IntPtr hSubMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);    // File menu
    uint menuItemId = GetMenuItemID(hSubMenu, 2);  // Open

    IntPtr ptr = SendMessage(hWnd, (uint)WM.COMMAND, (IntPtr)menuItemId, IntPtr.Zero);
}

private static IntPtr GetWindow(string windowTitle)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf(windowTitle, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
        {
            hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
            break;
        }
    }

    return hWnd;
}
```

How can I get the handles of the menu and submenu and the menuitemid from a Qt application?

// Anders

Comment: You should try sending right key events to the Qt app. Qt does not use Windows controls much, normally, so you need Qt specific mechanism if you really want to go through UI components.

Comment: The only robust way is to an appriopriate IPC mechanism and just tell the application to open the file.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it working using keybd_event, but I understand that IPC is the way to go. I'm discussing this with the programmers of the Qt application and they will add a way, but it will take some time. And time doesn't wait for noone, and so doesn't the user... Thank you again!

Comment: I think the answer to this question will help:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238883/windows-ui-automation-not-showing-all-child-elements