# Send a click event to a button (a child element) of a parent element by UI Automation in a program made by Qt

Tags: c#, qt, ui-automation, windows-messages, white-framework

## **My Application Framework: C#.Net**

.

## **Target Application Framework: Qt**

.

## **My automation tools:**

- **TestStack/White**
- **Useful classes of System.Windows.Automation namespace**

I have a Qt application and i got one of its panels (dialer panel) by following codes **BUT** I can't get (find) any children element of it!

.............[image]

.

---

**Main part of my codes:**

```
var dialerWindow = mainWindow.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Panel>("DialerPageWindow");

TreeWalker walker = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker;

AutomationElement current = walker.GetFirstChild(dialerWindow.AutomationElement);

//Now current is NULL :(
```

.

---

I watched **dialerWindow** variable (DialerPageWindow) in VS. It's snapshot:
[image]

.

---

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239671/1474613) to a question by this title: *Windows UI Automation not showing all child elements?*

But

- **I nead a way to send a click event to this button.**
- **Please suggest any tools, library, third party library, windows message or... in C# to solve this problem**

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot it looks like the elements in the dialer window are nog exposed to UIAutomation.
Have you tried using [inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [winspector](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml) or any other spytool to see if the element is detectable?

If they are not detectable, then there are 2 options

1. You have access to the sources and implement a provider that exposes the element (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
   You are probably looking for [IRawElementProvider](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml)
2. You are bound to clicking coordinates (sorry)

If you have access to the code, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) GitHub repo on how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As a pyhtonist I can suggest [pytest-qt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-qt) plugin for pytest framework that may be useful for QT applications.

Comment: my application framework is `.NET`. Is your suggested plugin about `C#.Net` or `Python`?!!!

Comment: Yes, how about Python scripts? ;)

Comment: I've just started checking this approach for Python. Installed pytest (OK), failed to install pytest-qt (reverted back because PySide is required), failed to install PySide (need more investigation). So getting started with that looks not friendly. Sorry. Probably someone could suggest you any approach for C#.